# Why is my pygame not responding when add buttons?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to add buttons into my pygame platformer but when I run I either can't click the buttons or the game won't respond depending on if I add pygame.display.update or not.

```
run = True
start_game = False
while run:
clock.tick(27)
#sets fps to 27

    if start_game == False:
        if start_button.draw(win):
            start_game = True
        if quit_button.draw(win):
            run = False

        pygame.display.update()

    else:

        platform_img.draw(win)
```

Here is my code for when clicking the buttons and depending on whether I add the pygame.display.update() the buttons either won't work or the program won't respond

```
class Button():
    def __init__ (self, x, y, image, scale):
        width = image.get_width()
        height = image.get_height()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(width * scale), int(height * scale)))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)
        self.clicked = False

    def draw(self, surface):
        action = False
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
                self.clicked = True
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
            self.clicked = False

        surface.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
        return action
```

This is my button class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the events in the application loop. See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) respectively [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

For example, add an event loop and the `QUIT` event:

```py
while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    # handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    if start_game == False:
        if start_button.draw(win):
            start_game = True
        if quit_button.draw(win):
            run = False
    else:
        platform_img.draw(win)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Note, the typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit frames per second to limit CPU usage